# Add list of contacts to email template from apex

Tags: apex, email-template, apex-email-service

I have a list of contacts that was generated generically in code.
At the end of the class I need to send email to a user. 
Email should include the list of contacts. (I'm using email tamplate).

How can I add this list of contacts to email before sending it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the email template, you can add a variable. So in the class, you can replace the variable with the list of contact.

Here for the example :
- in email template, add {!table_contact} at Body email.

- in the class, get the template with query. For ex :
  EmailTemplate et = [Select id,htmlValue,subject from EmailTemplate limit 1];
- Create a var string that filled with list data of contact (for example I create temp var).
- And than replace the htmlBody from email template.
  String htmlBody = et.HtmlValue;
  htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!table_contact}', temp);

Hope this will help.